# What is the link between g++ and gcc-c++ in Fedora's DNF repositories?

Tags: fedora, dnf

On Fedora 35:

```
# dnf install g++   
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:14 ago on Fri May  6 09:44:09 2022.
Package gcc-c++-11.3.1-2.fc35.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

```
# dnf info g++   
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:26 ago on Fri May  6 09:44:09 2022.
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I know `gcc-c++` is a package, which I should be installing if I want to compile C++.

Why does installing (and even removing!) `g++` work if it is not a package?

Bonus question: how can I check if `gcc-c++` is installed by only referencing `g++` and not its real name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `dnf install <something>`, it will first look for a package name `<something>`, but then it will look for a package that *provides* `<something>`. A "provides" value is effectively a virtual package name (set using the `Provides:` keyword in the RPM spec file).

We can see what packages *provide* `g++` by running:

```
dnf repoquery --whatprovides g++
```

Which (on Fedora 35) produces:

```
gcc-c++-0:11.2.1-1.fc35.i686
gcc-c++-0:11.2.1-1.fc35.x86_64
gcc-c++-0:11.3.1-2.fc35.x86_64
```

The `dnf repoquery` command queries your repository configuration. You can also ask the same question about locally installed packages using `rpm -q --whatprovides`, so to do this:

> Bonus question: how can I check if gcc-c++ is installed by only referencing g++ and not its real name?

Just run:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides g++
```

The return code will tell you whether any installed package provides `g++`.

---

This feature is often used to specify package dependencies that are linked to a particular capability, rather than a specific package. For example, if you have something that requires a webserver, rather than making it depend on a particular package (e.g., `httpd` or `nginx`), you can write in your spec file:

```
Requires: webserver
```

And then if any one of these packages is installed the dependency will be satisfied:

```
$ dnf repoquery --whatprovides webserver
caddy-0:2.3.0-2.fc35.x86_64
httpd-0:2.4.51-2.fc35.x86_64
httpd-0:2.4.53-1.fc35.x86_64
lighttpd-0:1.4.59-3.fc35.x86_64
lighttpd-0:1.4.64-1.fc35.x86_64
nginx-1:1.20.1-6.fc35.x86_64
nginx-1:1.20.2-1.fc35.x86_64
```